# How to have persistent header in emacs CSV mode and narrow to exclude first line

Tags: csv, emacs

I have started to use emacs CSV mode to view CSV files, and have discovered the ability to set a header line, which makes it much nicer when scrolling a large file. However, when you are viewing the top of the buffer, the header line is shown twice (once as the header, and once as the first line of the buffer). I can manually narrow the buffer to exclude the first line.

I would like my csv mode hook to automatically enable the header line, followed by narrowing the buffer, e.g.:

```
  (defun my-csv-mode-hook ()
    (csv-align-mode 1)
    (csv-header-line)
    (narrow-to-region
     (save-excursion
       (beginning-of-buffer)
       (forward-line 1)
       (point))
     (point-max)))
  (add-hook 'csv-mode-hook 'my-csv-mode-hook)
```

However, this incorrectly results in the *second* line of the file being used as the header. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The weird thing is that when I separately evaluate `(csv-header-line)` and then `(narrow-to-region (save-excursion (beginning-of-buffer) (forward-line 1) (point)) (point-max))`, everything works as expected. The issue seems to be that when they're inside the function, they're not being executed in the expected order.